# How to set NSScrollView to not auto-hide scroller?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsscrollview

When you stop to scroll an `NSScrollView`, it will auto-hide the scroller.
How can I disable that?
I can not find any property that can change this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `autohidesScrollers` property of `NSScrollView` is not taken into account for scroll views that use elastic scrolling (the default).
To permanantly make the scrollers visible, you could set the `scrollerStyle` to `.legacy` and `autohidesScrollers` to `false`.

```swift
self.collectionView.enclosingScrollView?.scrollerStyle = .legacy
self.collectionView.enclosingScrollView?.autohidesScrollers = false
```